# Create multiple html static files with Yew

Tags: rust, webassembly, yew

Is it possible to create more than one HTML file (with relative JS & WASM modules) from a single [Yew](https://yew.rs) project. For example, here I create one artifact with the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

Is it possible to make multiple instance of this and create few HTML output?

Answer (score 1):

## if you are meaning multiple pages within the same website

(For example, example.com/page1 & example.com/page2)

There is a feature called Router in yew

https://yew.rs/docs/concepts/router

**if you are meaning hosting multiple website on the same trunk** 
(For example, hosting both website1.com & website2.com on the same trunk)

I think it is not possible

--
I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: You are correct, I have now advanced in my project and I use yew router functions, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by [create more than one HTML file]?

each time you call the render it will render your page components.
if you did multiple calls, the components will be duplicated on the same page.
example:

```
fn main() {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

if you wanna build the entire application use router to switch between the pages.

Comment: For instance, I would like to create two static html pages from two different components. The code you have written, render the content in a unique index.html file. When I would be nice to have two of them for two different component. (i.e. index_for_comp_1.html and index_for_comp_2.html).  Thanks for the response!